# Pasting from register to command line inserts ^M instead of new line

Tags: search, command-line, cut-copy-paste

Say I want to search for multiple lines (or do anything with them in the command line).

I yank some lines and enter search mode (<kbd>/</kbd>).

I press <kbd>Ctrl + r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to paste what I just yanked, but I get `^M` for the line breaks so the search is unsuccessful unless I change the `^M` to `\n`.

This is on ubuntu using awesomewm and st terminal.
I suspect it could be an issue with my terminal as opposed to vim.

Here is a gif illustrating this:

[image: Here is a gif illustrating this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the contents of the register like this to escape the newlines:

```
:let @0=substitute(@0, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
```

And then just do your command like normal using Ctrl-R.

I rarely run into this use case so I guess this is good enough, but I still don't understand why vim behaves like this so would be great if someone else has a better solution.

You could add this to a function in your vimrc to do the substitution and then search if you liked, but I prefer not to add too much custom stuff so that when I log onto other systems I don't need to depend on having my vimrc.